# Pass uninitialized struct to a function

Tags: go

Let say I have a function that handles request body in general

```golang
func GetReqBody(r *http.Request) (interface {}, error){
    var data interface{}
    decorder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    decorder.DisallowUnknownFields()
    err := decorder.Decode(&data)
    return data, err
}
```

Then in the controller, I will have to do type assertion

```golang
func post(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data, err := utils.GetReqBody(r)

    //req.User is a struct
    newUser, ok := data.(req.User)

    // ...
}
```

Is it possible to encapsulate the type assertion login inside the `GetReqBody` function? To do that I will need to pass the struct into the function, yet as it is not a value I am unable to do so.

Comment: `data.(req.User)` suggests that, for some reason, you assume that `json.Decoder` knows exactly what the concrete type should be into which to decode the body, even though you're passing it a pointer to an uninitialized empty interface. That's not gonna happen. Whenever you pass `*interface{}` the result is not some struct like `req.User`, but always one of the predeclared, builtin types that the `encoding/json` package supports, like `[]interface{}`, or `map[string]interface{}` or `int`, `json.Decoder` will never choose `req.User`, *you* have to choose it, and *you* have to pass it explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Is it possible to encapsulate the type assertion login inside the `GetReqBody` function?"* -- No, it's not possible, not in any useful way.

---

However you could simplify your code thus:

```golang
func GetReqBody(r *http.Request, data interface{}) error {
    decorder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    decorder.DisallowUnknownFields()
    return decorder.Decode(data)
}
```

```golang
func post(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var newUser req.User
    if err := utils.GetReqBody(r, &newUser); err != nil {
        // handle err
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this is really helpful.